# Proving $\mathrm{Aut} \;\Bbb{Z}\cong \Bbb{Z_2}$

Tags: group-theory

I have been asked to prove $\mathrm{Aut}\; \Bbb{Z}\cong \Bbb{Z_2}$.

I figured that if I prove that $\mathrm{Aut}\; \Bbb{Z}$ has two elements, then I'm done. Clearly, $f(a)=a$ and $g(a)=-a$ can be those two automorphisms. Based on some rough calculations, I know there can't be any more automorphisms. Does this form a proof by any stretch of imagination?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, assuming you have an actual argument for why there are no others, yes. But it is hard to guess what you mean by calculations (especially rough ones).

Comment: if you write $a = f(1)$, then by the homomorphism property your map has the form $f(m) = am$. if $a$ were zero, the map wouldn't be injective. and if it's anything other than $\pm 1$, then it can't be surjective. so there are only two possibilities, and you've seen they are both valid.

Comment: Automorphisms of a group always form a group (this is a theorem). As you have shown that the two you have are *all* the automorphisms, then your automorphism group has order two. Thus, $\operatorname{Aut}(G)\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$, as required.

Comment: Presumably, $\text{Aut}\mathbb Z$ refers to the additive group of integers, not to the ring of integers (which has only one automorphism) or to the multiplicative semigroup of integers (which has uncountably many automorphisms) or to the linear order of the integers (which has a countable infinity of automorphisms) or $...$.  But it would be better to say in the question what structure on $\mathbb Z$ is intended, rather than having people guess.

Comment: @Andreas: Or the additive group of integers as an ordered group, which also have only one automorphism...

Comment: Well, it *is* tagged group theory, and if it was going to be any fancy kind of group then the OP would know enough to specify the type of structure we're dealing with...

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, if we set $G=\mathbb Z=\langle x\rangle$ so $G$ be infinite and if $f\in \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z)$ then $f(x)$ **must** be a generator of $G$ itself. Now think of how many generators $G$ has? This is very interesting to me because an infinite group has a finite automorphism group.

Comment: Nice, Babak! (+1)